# Angular 2 AOT additional dependency in subclass

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class UserService that inherits from AuthHttpServiceBase. AuthHttpServiceBase has a constructor that requires sessionStore, httpClient and configManager - UserService has a dependency on authRedirect as well. So I have the following setup:

HttpServiceBase:

```
import { Logger } from '../utils/logger';
import { ConfigurationManager } from '../utils/configuration-manager';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export abstract class HttpServiceBase {
    constructor(protected configManager: ConfigurationManager) {}

    protected get authApiUrl(): Observable<string> {
        return this.configManager.get('authApiUrl');
    }

    protected get signingApiUrl(): Observable<string> {
        return this.configManager.get('signingApiUrl');
    }

    protected handleError<T>(methodName: string, err: any, source: Observable<T> = null): Observable<any> {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred.
            Logger.error(`API call ${methodName} failed: ${err.error.message}`);
        }
        else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code. The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            Logger.error(`API call ${methodName} failed with status ${err.status}: ${JSON.stringify(err.error)}`);
        }

        return Observable.throw(err);
    }
}
```

AuthHttpServiceBase:

```
import { HttpServiceBase } from './http-service-base';
import { Logger } from '../utils/logger';
import { SessionData } from '../security/session-data';
import { SessionStore } from '../persistance/session-store';
import { ConfigurationManager } from '../utils/configuration-manager';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export abstract class AuthHttpServiceBase extends HttpServiceBase {     
    constructor(protected sessionStore: SessionStore, protected httpClient: HttpClient, protected configManager: ConfigurationManager) {
        super(configManager)
    }

    // Base class implementation...
}
```

UserService:

```
import { AuthRedirect } from '../security/auth-redirect';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../entities/user';
import { ConfigurationManager } from '../utils/configuration-manager';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { SessionStore } from '../persistance/session-store';
import { AuthHttpServiceBase } from '../http/auth-http-service-base';

@Injectable()
export class UserService extends AuthHttpServiceBase {
    constructor(private authRedirect: AuthRedirect, sessionStore: SessionStore, httpClient: HttpClient, configManager: ConfigurationManager) {
        super(sessionStore, httpClient, configManager);
    }

    // UserService implementation...
}
```

This runs fine in dev using JIT compilation (using Angular 4.3 + Webpack), but during AOT compilation I get the following error:

TS2417: Class static side 'typeof UserService' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof AuthHttpServiceBase'. Types of property 'ctorParameters' are incompatible.

I'm a bit at a loss as to what's going on here - surely it must be possible to define additional dependencies in a subclass constructor?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-starter",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "description": "An Angular Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular2",
    "angular4",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:travis": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean": "npm cache clean --force && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
    "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "node": "node",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
    "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "deepmerge": "^1.5.0",
    "fuse.js": "^3.0.5",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-webstorage": "^1.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.3.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.39",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.16",
    "@types/fuse": "^2.5.2",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.5",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "find-root": "^1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "inline-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
    "ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "ngc-webpack": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "^3.0.2",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.8.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "~1.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "tslint": "~4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "~2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import './rxjs-extensions';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ENV_PROVIDERS } from './environment';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ExternalRootComponent } from './external-root.component';
import { InternalRootComponent } from './internal-root.component';
import { PageHeaderComponent } from './page-header.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './core/security/auth-interceptor';

import '../scss/style.scss';

/**
 * `AppModule` is the main entry point into Angular2's bootstraping process
 */
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ExternalRootComponent,
        InternalRootComponent,
        PageHeaderComponent,
        NotFoundComponent
    ],
    /**
     * Import Angular's modules.
     */
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    /**
     * Expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection.
     */
    providers: [
        ENV_PROVIDERS,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Wild guess but check AuthHttpServiceBase. Think your .super is wrong.

Comment: Can you post your imports please? Perhaps you are importing types from different locations

Comment: Added imports as requested - not sure what you mean with importing types from different locations?

Comment: @Swoox could you please elaborate? Dont' see anything wrong with the super call in AuthHttpServiceBase?

Comment: @William was a wild guess just to double check.

Comment: @William Can you also post your HttpServiceBase?

Comment: @MarkusKollers Sure :)

Comment: Ok, I've copied your code into an empty Angular-CLI project with the latest dependencies. Everything is fine on running "ng serve --aot". What about your package.json and your app.module?

Comment: Strange... I'm using Angular starter, posting them in a sec.